# Android animate Highlighting textView

Tags: android, animation, textview

i want  to animate textView for create karaoke .

I've used the following code to do it .

but in many devices run was pretty bad.

When the text has been highlighted it was shaked .
And speed of this acting in different devices, is different

```
 String  textString = "my karaoke string";
        int i = textString.length();
        ii++;
        Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(textString);
        spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), ii , i, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        mSwitcher.setText(spanText);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are doing this inside a loop or similar. Take a look at [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 String  textString = "my karaoke string";      
 List<String> uu = split3(textString, " ");
 Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(textString);
 spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00),textString.indexOf(uu.get(1))  ,textString.indexOf(uu.get(1))+uu.get(1).length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 textView.setText(spanText);
```

Comment: private static List<String> split3(final String str, String m_separatorChar) {
  final List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>(10);
  int pos, prev = 0;
  while ((pos = str.indexOf(m_separatorChar, prev)) != -1) {
   res.add(str.substring(prev, pos));
   prev = pos + 1; // start from next char after separator
  }
  res.add(str.substring(prev));
  return res;
 }